# Excluding results with an empty value for a field

Tags: php, mysql

For the query below, some results have nothing in the database for "age."  How can I exclude these values that have nothing for "age"?

```
$sqlStr3 = "SELECT
                 username 
                 ,loginid
                 ,age  

        FROM login
        ORDER BY age ASC
           LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage";
```

Answer (score 1):

If age defaults to NULL (the typical case), add a simple `WHERE age NOT NULL` check:

```
SELECT
   username 
   ,loginid
   ,age  

FROM login
WHERE age NOT NULL
ORDER BY age ASC
LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage
```

Comment: This works, but it adds an extraneous where clause when there's a built in operator for that.  Unnecessary where clauses add additional overhead. http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2008/10/31/how-expensive-is-a-where-clause-in-mysql/

Comment: @Nilpo I'm not sure that a performance optimization is needed here.  Also, the linked article is of dubious quality. I am not a MySQL expert but benchmarks are so rarely done correctly I'm naturally a skeptic.

Comment: I'm certainly not suggesting it's written in stone, but a single select would have to be faster than a compound one.  And I personally believe that *every* query should be as optimized as possible.  That's just a good habit.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Where clause but it's easier and faster to just add the `IS NOT NULL` operator to your SELECT for that field.

```
$sqlStr3 = "SELECT
                 username 
                 ,loginid
                 ,age IS NOT NULL

        FROM login
        ORDER BY age ASC
           LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage";
```

[Comparison Functions and Operators](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_is-not-null)